# Function pointer for inverse of exp function in c

Tags: c, function-pointers

I am trying to define a function pointer which calculates e^-x.
Something similar to C# equivalent:

```
    Func<double, double> f = x => Math.Exp(-x);
```

I tried in vain by doing something like:

```
double(*negativeExp(double x))(double) {
    double eValue = exp(1);
    return  pow(eValue, -x);
}
```

Any ideas.

Comment: Why are you returning a function pointer?

Comment: Note that you cannot define a lambda in C, and you certainly cannot capture variables. So your problem is how to declare the function type, not the body.

Comment: Side note: Why didn't you simply call `exp(-x)` in the function body?

Comment: C doesn't have a native closure construction, so it's not entirely trivial to bind function arguments and pass the bound callable around.

Comment: @2501 because I have a function which accepts function pointers to operations like these

Comment: @KerrekSB  thanks for letting me know that C does not have native closure constructs

Comment: @Groo thanks for letting me know that C does not have native closure constructs

Comment: @PeterG. because  I have a function which accepts function pointers to operations like these

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code for the function would be:

```
double f(double x)
{
    return exp(-x);
}
```

Then you can make a pointer to that function. Sample use:

```
int main(void)
{
    double (*p)(double) = &f;

    printf("f(1) == %f", p(1));
}
```

Comment: Is there a difference between `double (*p)(double) = &f;` and `double (*p)(double) = f;` ?

Comment: @Pierre there is no difference.

Answer (score 0):

To add to the answer, as noted in comments, it's not possible to write lambdas/closures in C and capture variables the way you would do in C#.

There are no classes either, so no magical "thiscall" which would pass the instance reference to the function. This means you need to pass any "state" manually through parameters. So, something that would look like this in C#:

```
public class SomeClass
{
     private int _someParameter;

     public SomeClass(int p) { _someParameter = p; }

     public int DoStuff(Func<int> process) => process(_someParameter);
}

// somewhere in main
var s = new SomeClass(5);
var result = s.DoStuff(x => x * 2);
```

Would look something like this in C:

```
struct SomeClass
{
    int someParameter;
};

// all "member functions" need to get the "this" reference

void SomeClassInit(struct SomeClass *_this, int p)
{
    _this->someParameter = p;
}

int DoStuff(struct SomeClass *_this, int(*process)(int))
{
    return process(_this->someParameter);
}

int Process(int x)
{
    return x * 2;
}

// somewhere in main
struct SomeClass s;
SomeClassInit(&s, 5);
return DoStuff(&s, Process);
```